# Overriding the serialize_field() method in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, super

Im using code from Scrapy documentation, with "Product" class item created

```
from scrapy.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class ProductXmlExporter(XmlItemExporter):

    def serialize_field(self, field, name, value):
        if field == 'price':
            return f'$ {str(value)}'
        return super(Product, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)
```

and always get error from command line

**return super(Product, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)

TypeError: super(Product, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**

I am new to Python so any help would be appreciated and did some research on "super" function but still dont understand how to connect this class inside code in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with scrapy but how is the Product class related to ProductXmlExporter? The super keyword does not accept unrelated classes so your call should really be `return super(XmlItemExporter, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)`, assuming you want to call `serialize_field` method of XmlItemExporter.

Comment: Its actually using BaseItemExporter since I needed to override some other functions also, so I needed to implement my own exporter as written in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html so as You said, requires XmlItemExporter (BaseItemExporter) instead Product class for super but in docs it was written with Product class

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Is ProductXmlExporter subclassed from BaseItemExporter? In that case you can call super with BaseItemExporter. As for the docs it could be a typo because I cannot see how Product and ProductXmlExporter are related.