# XML exporter serialize_field in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, super

Im using code from Scrapy documentation https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html, with "Product" class item created

```
from scrapy.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class ProductXmlExporter(XmlItemExporter):

    def serialize_field(self, field, name, value):
        if field == 'price':
            return f'$ {str(value)}'
        return super(Product, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)
```

and always get error from command line

```
return super(Product, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)
TypeError: super(Product, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I dont know if thats typo in docs, but super function cannot accept Product class, it should be ProductXmlExporter

I am new to Python so any help would be appreciated and did some research on "super" function but still dont understand how to connect this class inside code in this example.

Comment: You're right, that's a typo in docs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396610/overriding-the-serialize-field-method-in-scrapy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding the serialize\_field() method in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396610/overriding-the-serialize-field-method-in-scrapy)